# Select CSS with a part of SVG inserted within an object

Tags: javascript, css, svg

In a form insert various objects dynamically and eventually these objects would be like this:

```
<object class="redDiv" type="image/svg+xml" data="Immagini/Cluster/MarkerBalloon.svg">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 35.000000 46.000000" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
<metadata>
Created by potrace 1.13, written by Peter Selinger 2001-2015
</metadata>
<g transform="translate(0.000000,46.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#000000" stroke="none">
<path d="M133 440 c-54 -24 -78 -63 -92 -153 -15 -103 -25 -287 -14 -287 13 0 179 110 240 158 69 55 86 90 81 159 -4 44 -11 60 -38 88 -31 32 -82 55 -120 55 -8 0 -34 -9 -57 -20z"/>
</g>
</svg>
</object>
```

where each object to insert a different class (in this case, for example, is inserted "redDiv"), and thanks to this I should change the color of the svg.

I tried to make a selection in css type:

```
.redDiv svg g {
fill: red
}
```

but unfortunately does not select anything; I searched the internet but could not find anything ... I request you can change the color of SVG added to an object?

Comment: Works perfeclty fine for me. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aides/6n7gv5b2/)

Comment: ok, but in my form does not pick anything! plus I tried to select with jquery ($(".redDiv svg g")) and not select anything ..

Comment: Trying with the object already existing works, maybe it's because your selection is tried when the objects is not ready yet ?

Comment: have you tried to select this with jquery after the DOM is ready? try to use .ready and then call your function that effects <g>

Comment: you can't apply css on foreign documents from the main document. Are concerned : `<iframe>`, `<object>` and `<img>` tags. What you can do however for the two formers, is to access their document via their `contentDocument` property. From there, you can modify each of its nodes properties directly (including the `style` one) or even append a new stylesheet. Note that the access to `contentDocument` is limited by cross-origin policies.

Comment: @Kaiido this should probably be posted as an answer

Comment: @Aides this question is a duplicate, I don't think it needs an answer, the two received by the dupe I pointed to offer the explanation and the solution.

Comment: $("object").each(function(){ var svg = this.contentDocument.children; var g = svg[0].children[1]; g.style.fill = "red" }); thank you Kaiido